# (python) using graphics.py, moving an image to specific coordinates instead of move() function?

Tags: python, image, graphics

I'm using the graphics.py library and loading images from file.
for example:

```
myObject = Image(Point(pos_x,pos_y), 'filename.png') 
myObject.draw(window)
```

I'm then sliding them across the screen using the myObject.move(x,y) function.
The move function is smooth, but I really need to synchronize the movement with the current system time (in seconds, milliseconds, etc) so parts of the image hit exactly on the second, minute, hour.

If I use the move() function, it is not accurate and I can't tell it the exact position I want the image to be at a given millisecond, second, minute on the system clock -- I can only shift it around.

I tried undrawing the object, changing my pos_x/y coordinates, and redrawing inside my while loop:

```
myObject.undraw()
myObject = Image(Point(pos_x,pos_y), 'filename.png') 
myObject.draw(window)
```

... but omg its horrible. It's re-loading the file from the filesystem every times per second.  I know this isn't the way to do this. Is there any way to move an image to exact coordinates without having to re-initalize the whole file from disk?

Basically outlined the whole problem, above. Thanks in advance!